# Programa en C++ se cierra en consola, pero funciona en IDE

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Sucede que al ejecutar el programa desde el IDE de Code Blocks para las pruebas, este funciona de forma adecuada, sin embargo, al generarse el ejecutable en la carpeta del proyecto y ejecutarlo, solo funciona el case a, pero los case b y c se cierran tan pronto como los elijo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int valores[10];
    int opcion;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        bool valid = false;
        while (!valid)
        {
            cout << "Ingrese un valor entero y positivo: ";
            cin >> valores[i];
            if (cin.fail() || valores[i] < 0)
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
                cout << "Valor inválido, inténtelo de nuevo." << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                valid = true;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Los valores ingresados son: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "Valor " << valores[i] << " en la posición " << i << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << "MENU DE OPCIONES" << endl << endl;
    cout << "METODOS DE BUSQUEDA:" << endl;
    cout << "1. SECUENCIAL." << endl;
    cout << "2. BINARIA." << endl;
    cout << "3. INTERPOLACION." << endl << endl;
    cout << "Seleccione una opcion: ";

    cin >> opcion;
    switch (opcion)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        int valor;
        bool encontrado = false;
        cout << "Ha seleccionado la busqueda secuencial." << endl;
        do
        {
            cout << "Ingrese el valor a buscar: ";
            cin >> valor;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (valores[i] == valor)
                {
                    cout << "El valor " << valor << " se encuentra en la posicion " << i << " del arreglo." << endl;
                    cout << "Se realizaron " << i+1 << " iteraciones." << endl;
                    encontrado = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!encontrado)
            {
                cout << "El valor " << valor << " no se encuentra en el arreglo. Intente de nuevo." << endl;
            }
        }
        while (!encontrado);
        break;
    }



    break;

    case 2:
    {
        int valor;
        bool encontrado = false;
        cout << "Ha seleccionado la busqueda binaria." << endl;
        do
        {
            cout << "Ingrese el valor a buscar: ";
            cin >> valor;
            int inicio = 0;
            int fin = 9;
            int iteraciones = 0;
            while (inicio <= fin)
            {
                int medio = (inicio + fin) / 2;
                iteraciones++;
                if (valores[medio] == valor)
                {
                    cout << "El valor " << valor << " se encuentra en la posicion " << medio << " del arreglo." << endl;
                    cout << "Se realizaron " << iteraciones << " iteraciones." << endl;
                    encontrado = true;
                    break;
                }
                else if (valores[medio] < valor)
                {
                    inicio = medio + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    fin = medio - 1;
                }
            }
            if (!encontrado)
            {
                cout << "El valor " << valor << " no se encuentra en el arreglo. Intente de nuevo." << endl;
            }
        }
        while (!encontrado);
        break;
    }


    case 3:
{
    int valor;
    bool encontrado = false;
    cout << "Ha seleccionado la busqueda por interpolacion." << endl;

    // Ordena el arreglo
    sort(valores, valores + 10);

    do
    {
        cout << "Ingrese el valor a buscar: ";
        cin >> valor;
        int inicio = 0;
        int fin = 9;
        int iteraciones = 0;
        while (inicio <= fin && valor >= valores[inicio] && valor <= valores[fin])
        {
            int pos = inicio + ((valor - valores[inicio]) * (fin - inicio)) / (valores[fin] - valores[inicio]);
            iteraciones++;
            if (valores[pos] == valor)
            {
                cout << "El valor " << valor << " se encuentra en la posicion " << pos << " del arreglo." << endl;
                cout << "Se realizaron " << iteraciones << " iteraciones." << endl;
                encontrado = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (valores[pos] < valor)
            {
                inicio = pos + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                fin = pos - 1;
            }
        }
        if (!encontrado)
        {
            cout << "El valor " << valor << " no se encuentra en el arreglo. Intente de nuevo." << endl;
        }
    }
    while (!encontrado);
    break;
}



    default:
        cout << "Opcion invalida. Intente de nuevo." << endl;
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ese break al cerrar el caso 1...

Comment: @Alfabravo el `break` no es normal, pero tampoco es problemático, simplemente es dead code

Comment: @Alfabravo Gracias por tu respuesta. Aún habiendo eliminado ese break que estaba de más, el programa sigue fallando.

Comment: Estoy probando tu código [acá](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/B59JTVE4Co8) y no lo replico. Sale un resultado raro en la opción 3 pero las tres funciones responden "lo esperado"

Comment: Escribí `cin.get()` antes del return y el programa se va a detener hasta que toques ENTER. Deberías debugear el código para entender mejor la causa del problema.

Comment: @andres_rr creo que el problema es el que indica Mateo, te sugeriría que evites correr el ejecutable directamente, y en lugar de eso utilices el command prompt y lo ejecutes desde ahí

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int valores[10];
    int opcion;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        bool valid = false;
        while (!valid)
        {
            cout << "Ingrese un valor entero y positivo: ";
            cin >> valores[i];
            if (cin.fail() || valores[i] < 0)
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
                cout << "Valor inválido, inténtelo de nuevo." << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                valid = true;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Los valores ingresados son: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "Valor " << valores[i] << " en la posición " << i << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << "MENU DE OPCIONES" << endl << endl;
    cout << "METODOS DE BUSQUEDA:" << endl;
    cout << "1. SECUENCIAL." << endl;
    cout << "2. BINARIA." << endl;
    cout << "3. INTERPOLACION." << endl << endl;
    cout << "Seleccione una opcion: ";

    cin >> opcion;
    switch (opcion)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        int valor;
        bool encontrado = false;
        cout << "Ha seleccionado la busqueda secuencial." << endl;
        do
        {
            cout << "Ingrese el valor a buscar: ";
            cin >> valor;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (valores[i] == valor)
                {
                    cout << "El valor " << valor << " se encuentra en la posicion " << i << " del arreglo." << endl;
                    cout << "Se realizaron " << i+1 << " iteraciones." << endl;
                    encontrado = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!encontrado)
            {
                cout << "El valor " << valor << " no se encuentra en el arreglo. Intente de nuevo." << endl;
            }
        }
        while (!encontrado);
        break;
    }



    break;

    case 2:
    {
        int valor;
        bool encontrado = false;
        cout << "Ha seleccionado la busqueda binaria." << endl;
        do
        {
            cout << "Ingrese el valor a buscar: ";
            cin >> valor;
            int inicio = 0;
            int fin = 9;
            int iteraciones = 0;
            while (inicio <= fin)
            {
                int medio = (inicio + fin) / 2;
                iteraciones++;
                if (valores[medio] == valor)
                {
                    cout << "El valor " << valor << " se encuentra en la posicion " << medio << " del arreglo." << endl;
                    cout << "Se realizaron " << iteraciones << " iteraciones." << endl;
                    encontrado = true;
                    break;
                }
                else if (valores[medio] < valor)
                {
                    inicio = medio + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    fin = medio - 1;
                }
            }
            if (!encontrado)
            {
                cout << "El valor " << valor << " no se encuentra en el arreglo. Intente de nuevo." << endl;
            }
        }
        while (!encontrado);
        break;
    }


    case 3:
{
    int valor;
    bool encontrado = false;
    cout << "Ha seleccionado la busqueda por interpolacion." << endl;

    // Ordena el arreglo
    sort(valores, valores + 10);

    do
    {
        cout << "Ingrese el valor a buscar: ";
        cin >> valor;
        int inicio = 0;
        int fin = 9;
        int iteraciones = 0;
        while (inicio <= fin && valor >= valores[inicio] && valor <= valores[fin])
        {
            int pos = inicio + ((valor - valores[inicio]) * (fin - inicio)) / (valores[fin] - valores[inicio]);
            iteraciones++;
            if (valores[pos] == valor)
            {
                cout << "El valor " << valor << " se encuentra en la posicion " << pos << " del arreglo." << endl;
                cout << "Se realizaron " << iteraciones << " iteraciones." << endl;
                encontrado = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (valores[pos] < valor)
            {
                inicio = pos + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                fin = pos - 1;
            }
        }
        if (!encontrado)
        {
            cout << "El valor " << valor << " no se encuentra en el arreglo. Intente de nuevo." << endl;
        }
    }
    while (!encontrado);
    break;
}



    default:
        cout << "Opcion invalida. Intente de nuevo." << endl;
        break;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Agrega el encabezado #include <windows.h> para poder usar la función system("pause"); .Esta función hace que la consola se quede esperando a que pulses una tecla para salir.

Comment: Hola Gabriel, gracias por tu colaboración, las respuestas que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que edites la misma y expliques como soluciona el problema planteado, así evitarás recibir votos negativos, y el cierre de tu respuesta.